# PyCharm debug jump to

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LzEj.png

Hi,
I am using PyCharm 2.7.3, the newest version to this date
I am writing a simple script called hour4.py
I want to debug that script. So I hit Alt+Shift+F9 to open the debug script dialoague and then I choose from the list hour4.py. This is where it all goes wrong.
Instead of PyCharm debuggin my script hour4.py it jumps over to pydevd.py and starts debugging that one instead. In the bottom of my screen it shows its debugging hour4.py but its clearly not.
Thanks for anything that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Run` | `View Breakpoints` and disable the **Python Exception Breakpoints**:

[image: disable]

You also need to ensure that your script has no syntax errors, otherwise it will fail to load and you will step into `pydevd.py` instead.

Comment: Right, but you need to **disable** that.

Comment: yes I did but then I no longer see the Thunder symbol that points me 
to the right spot                                                                               http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/324/eidh.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/DtJ83JV.png                     http://i.imgur.com/18qPfC4.png             http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/26/zreg.png

Comment: the images in order     1. the breakpoint in the script hour4.py              2. the debug window dialouge showing that I want to debug my hour4.py script   3. what  happens once I hit debug

Comment: Once again, disable exception breakpoints, put line breakpoints in your script, press debug. Make sure your script has no syntax errors and can at least start.

Comment: script does not execute properly. I get errors, like i would expect because i put in breakpoints. how do I do a factory reset?

Comment: Breakpoints can be put on syntax valid lines of code. If the script doesn't run and displays syntax errors, you cannot debug it.

Comment: I will do a reinstall later. Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure how reinstall will help you. Syntax errors are displayed in the editor and file name has weaving underline until you fix them all. You don't have to run your code to detect and fix syntax problems, the editor already shows them.

Comment: I have a desktop that has it working properly. I will copy the files to my laptop.

Comment: To start from scratch [delete IDE folders](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/3neQi1n.png ----whenever I hit debug it gives me the errors that are in this file: pydevd.py a script that I did not create. It is really annoying considering I paid $100 for this POS (piece of software) ;)

Comment: Contact support with the sample project to reproduce.